# Different views based on user table information in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a project in Laravel 7 that has a column in the user table called  `organ_id` that has different numbers for different users (1,2,...)
Now I want to use `organ_id` inside my controller, which is as follows, and by using `if`, different information is given to each user according to the organ number.

##### `ProductsController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check())
{
    $organ_id = Auth::user()->getId();
}

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function test(Request $request) {
        if ($organ_id == 1) {
            function orders(Request $request) {
                $data = DB::table('products_1')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                    ->paginate(14);

                return view('products', compact('data'));
            }

            function posts(Request $request) {
                $data = DB::table('posts')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                    ->paginate(25);

                return view('posts', compact('data'));
            }

            /*
              other functions
              .
              .
              .
             */
        }

        if ($organ_id == 2) {
            function orders(Request $request) {
                $data = DB::table('products_2')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                    ->paginate(14);

                return view('products', compact('data'));
            }

            function posts(Request $request) {
                $data = DB::table('posts')
                    ->orderBy('writer_id', 'asc')
                    ->paginate(10);

                return view('posts', compact('data'));
            }

            /*
              other functions
              .
              .
              .
             */
        }
    }
}
```

##### `User.php`

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->organ_id;
}
```

Since it is not possible to use `if` in the controller, I wrote the `public function test()` and put `if` inside this function.

Unfortunately, in this case, the browser can not find the orders function.

Comment: Oh my god, I am really sorry to be so harsh with you, but your code is super horrible, I have never saw a `function` inside a `method` like you did, that is an absolute **NO-NO**. That code is really bad. You don't write anything outside a `class` (except `namespace` and `use`), that `if` is not correct, that should be inside the method `test`. And all those `functions`, what are you trying to do with `posts`, `organs`, etc ? You do not create a `function` and return the function... Explain 100% what you want to achieve. with that code. Also, read the documentation as this is never recommended

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```
$organ_id = User::where('id',auth()->user()->id)->pluck('organ_id')->first();
    if ($organ_id == 1) {
      //code
    }
```